# Need to get file info before it will be printed using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to get the name and size of the file that has been sent to printer. So I need to get info about it BEFORE file is printed.

I have tried to work with files in Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS, but I can't get any info from .SHD and .SPL files even if I pause the print work.

I started to look for some solution using Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer.
Is it a correct approach? Maybe I should use some particular methods or something?

I tried this code, but it shows a mistake

```
$comp = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).Name
if ( (Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0)
{
  Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -filter 'name="spooler"' -ComputerName $comp | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name StopService | out-null
  $name = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_PrintJob).Document
  $size = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_PrintJob).Size
  $time = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_PrintJob).StartTime
  "$comp,$name,$size,$time" | Out-file C:\Scripts\PrintJobs.csv -Append
  Set-Service spooler -ComputerName $comp -Status Running
}
```

What is wrong?

PowerShell is a new thing for me and for now I'm totally lost with this task

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know when to run the powershell I don't see how you can get this information "Before" the print job is sent.  You would have to keep the spooler "Paused" and then when the script is run set it to Running and then pause it again until the next time the script is run.

one thing is that "Get-WmiObject Win32_PrintJob" will most likely return a collection of all current spooled jobs. so your code should look something like this to get the information you are looking for:

```
$comp = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).Name
$jobs=Get-WmiObject Win32_PrintJob
$jobInfo = $jobs | ForEach-Object {"$comp,$($_.Document),$($_.Size),$($_.StartTime)"}
$jobInfo | Out-file C:\Scripts\PrintJobs.csv -Append
```